# Button looking really weird on storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, image, uibutton

I am trying to fix a cool looking button but for some reason it is looking really weird in the storyboard. Anybody knows why?

[image]

That is how it looks when i use the picture i have as the background

[image]

And this is how it looks when i set the picture i have as image.

This is the image that i am using for the button:

[image]

So my question is basically is there anyway to use this image to fill out the whole button area so it looks good?

Thank you

**EDIT**

When i used andres code:

[image]

**EDIT1**

Here is the final result:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to set the background image of a button ?Can you show the settings of the button on your storyboard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you have to set this up in code like this:

```
let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
let image = UIImage(named: "bt_bg")?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(insets)
button.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: .Normal)
```

the insets specify which parts of the image to preserve (in this case 10 points to preserve the rounded corners on the left and right side of the image) and which to repeat (everything within 10 points from the left and the right).

hope it helps.

Comment: Hi!

Thanks this actually worked. But i cant make the button bigger than the acutal size of the image. if you check my edit this is how it looks like when i change the width from 36 to 41

Comment: try to set the value 10 for all of your insets: top, left, bottom and right.

Comment: Well i copied your code so yea im 100% sure. BTW i meant that it looked like the edit when i changed the height not the width

Comment: changing all values to 10 (including the top and bottom ones) should do the trick. although it could look a bit weird in your case because your image contains a gradient.

Comment: yea it worked. But as you said it still looks weird. Guess there is nothing i can do about it. Thank you anyway

Comment: you're welcome. can you show what it finally looks like?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably using AspectFit as the view's content mode. I would try setting that to some version of "Fill". That looks like what using it as a background is doing. It is filling the button with your image and distorting it.

I'm not sure off the top of my head but maybe something like this may work

```
[[button imageView] setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
```